# how to compare the drawing lines is between 2 group of array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I wanna track the user's drawing line is between the 2 group of array values, for example I have draw one line in the canvas center, I have set 2 group of array object with x and y coordinate. how can I get the x and y coordinate compare with my arrays. if the line is not in between the 2 set of array then show answer wrong. please help

here is the codes:
    var coordsa=new Array();

```
coordsa.push({x:479,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:480,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:481,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:482,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:483,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:484,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:485,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:486,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:487,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:488,y:60});

var xcoorda =coordsa[0].x;
var ycoorda =coordsa[0].y;

var coordsb =new Array(); 

coordsb.push({x:467,y:74});
coordsb.push({x:468,y:75});
coordsb.push({x:469,y:75});
coordsb.push({x:470,y:77});
coordsb.push({x:471,y:78});
coordsb.push({x:472,y:80});
coordsb.push({x:473,y:80});
coordsb.push({x:474,y:81});
coordsb.push({x:475,y:82});
coordsb.push({x:476,y:83});

var xcoordb =coordsb[0].x;
var ycoordb =coordsb[0].y;

if ( coordsb[0].x > storeList[0].x && storeList[0].x < coordsa[0].x )
{   
console.log("corrct");
}
else
{
console.log("wrong");
}
```

In case you need the see the full code, please refer to the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html><head>
     <style>
       #contain {
          width: 500px;
         height: 120px;
         top : 15px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         position: relative;    
         }

         #layer1{background:url(http://docs.gimp.org/en/images/tutorials/straight-lines-6.png)} 
     </style>
  <script>
var touchList = [];
var storeList = [];
var checkList = [];
var check = 0;
    var currentPlates;
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var lastPt=null;
    var letsdraw = false;
    var offX = 440, offY = 25;


function init() {
    var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
    touchzone.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    touchzone.addEventListener("touchend", end, false);
    ctx = touchzone.getContext("2d");
  }

  function draw(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
var selectedCoordinate = new Object();
selectedCoordinate.x = e.touches[0].pageX;
selectedCoordinate.y = e.touches[0].pageY;
touchList.push(selectedCoordinate);
//console.log("X: " + e.touches[0].pageX + " Y: " + e.touches[0].pageY);

    if (lastPt != null) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastPt.x, lastPt.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
             e.touches[0].pageY - offY);
    ctx.stroke();
     }
    lastPt = {
         x: e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
         y: e.touches[0].pageY - offY
       };
    }

  function end(e) {

for(var i=0; i<touchList.length; i++)
{
storeList= touchList;
}
for(var i=0; i<touchList.length; i++)
{
console.log(storeList[i].x + " : " + storeList[i].y);
}


var coordsa=new Array(); 

coordsa.push({x:479,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:480,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:481,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:482,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:483,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:484,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:485,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:486,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:487,y:60});
coordsa.push({x:488,y:60});

var xcoorda =coordsa[0].x;
var ycoorda =coordsa[0].y;

var coordsb =new Array(); 

coordsb.push({x:467,y:74});
coordsb.push({x:468,y:75});
coordsb.push({x:469,y:75});
coordsb.push({x:470,y:77});
coordsb.push({x:471,y:78});
coordsb.push({x:472,y:80});
coordsb.push({x:473,y:80});
coordsb.push({x:474,y:81});
coordsb.push({x:475,y:82});
coordsb.push({x:476,y:83});

var xcoordb =coordsb[0].x;
var ycoordb =coordsb[0].y;

if ( coordsb[0].x > storeList[0].x && storeList[0].x < coordsa[0].x )
{   
console.log("corrct");
}
else
{
console.log("wrong");
}
var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
e.preventDefault();
    //Terminate touch path
    lastPt = null;
    }

 function clear_canvas_width ()
  {
touchList = [];
    var s = document.getElementById ("layer1");
    var w = s.width;
    s.width = 10;
    s.width = w;
  }

    </script>    
 </head>

  <body onload="init()">

   <div id="contain">

     <canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="440" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;z-index:0; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas> 

    </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you explain more ? especially 'a line is between the two sets of array' is a little bit cryptic to me..

Comment: I have a background images(one line), I will request user to draw on canvas following the image(one line). How am I going to know whether the drawing is out of the shape or not following the image image.

Comment: There is a line drawn on the canvas. Then the user has to follow that line the most closely possible. When he(she) is too far from the nearest segment, or if they keep on being too far (if you cumulate the errors), then the result will be : fail. If they get near from the last point without failing so far, result is pass. ??

Comment: Rq : given that we know the distance the user travelled so far, the criterium might be 'distance travelled while being near with no interruption > 0.6 * total segment distance.' (for instance).

Comment: yes. That's what I want in the program. but I don't know use what method to do this.what I think is make use of array to comparing the result. Can you teach me how to do the codes? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you combine your coordsa & coordsb, the resulting closed shape looks like this:

[image]

To see if the user touches completely inside this shape, you can use canvas's built in hit test

```
context.isPointInPath(TouchX,TouchY)
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/bK8Ue/

Comment: For my case, I wanna see whether the user is follow the background drawing. if I only locate one area it not that accurate. For example, I have a background image(one line), I will request user to draw on canvas following the image(one line). How am I going to know whether the user's drawing is out of the shape(line) or not following the image.

Comment: Draw a path around the area you want the user to stay within and then hit-test with isPointInPath.  If isPointInPath ever returns False, the user has gone outside your desired area.  Here is a Fiddle showing a single line and a bounding box around that line.  If the user ever drags outside that bounding box then they are "wrong":  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/bPpy2/

Comment: how about the line is curve? what method I should use?

Comment: Same method...Paths can be made of multiple lines and multiple curves.  Check out context.quadraticCurveTo and context.bezierCurveTo which add curves to your path.